# Error in hadoop environment setup for window 10

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup hadoop environment for window 10, after facing lot of errors all resourcemanager ,datanode and nodemanager are working(not shutting down) but there is new problem occured which is that datanode are not showing all menu options.

```
C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.3.5\hadoop-3.3.5\sbin>jps
11232 Jps
10712 NodeManager
7880 ResourceManager
4188 DataNode
```

I followed all steps of this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/vorpal56/5e2b67b6be3a827b85ac82a63a5b3b2e
[image]

Comment: It could be due to config or environment setup issues... Ensure that Hadoop config files are correctly set up, especially hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml. also check if DataNode process is running properly by examining the logs for any errors.

Comment: But how can i verify after configuration that datanode is working properly or not.